# I need a sql statement that allows me to split a description column into 4 columns

Tags: sql

I need a SQL statement that allows me to split a description column into 4 columns

The description holds the following with a delimiter of '='

```
Mary=123=456=payment
```

This needs to be split into the following:

```
Claimant   Voucher _no   Rec_NO   descr  
Mary       123           456      payment
```

Comment: The solution will vary depending on which RDBMS you are using. Can you be more specific about the database.

Comment: Split into 4 columns or into 4 rows? This greatly differentiates the process.

Comment: Data that needs to be split into four separate values is best stored in four separate columns, precisely so it doesn't have to be split up.

Answer (score 2):

SQL language is not for calculation purpose.use higher level(programming language,ORM) for  more speed.your RDBMS should be support sub-query, string functions([SUBSTRING](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/string-functions.html#function_substr),[LOCATE](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/string-functions.html#function_locate)) . following code in MySQL

http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!2/ec808/26

```
CREATE TABLE Table1(
data varchar(2000)
)

INSERT INTO Table1(data) values('Mary=123=456=payment');
INSERT INTO Table1(data) values('Mary232=123=456=payment');
SELECT SUBSTRING(data, 1,pos1-1) as Claimant       ,
SUBSTRING(data, pos1+1,pos2-pos1-1) as Voucher_no,
SUBSTRING(data, pos2+1,pos3-pos2-1) as Rec_NO,
SUBSTRING(data, pos3+1) as descr FROM (
 SELECT 

data,
LOCATE('=',`data`) as pos1,
LOCATE('=',`data`,LOCATE('=',`data`)+1) as pos2,
LOCATE('=',`data`,LOCATE('=',`data`,LOCATE('=',`data`)+1)+1) as pos3
FROM table1) as subq;
```

Answer (score 2):

Many RDBMS provides you with Regular Expression functions, either natively or via the extensions. As I come from PostgresSQL world and you haven't specified the RDBMS you're using, then I will give example how to do it in PostgreSQL.

You can use [regexp_split_to_table()](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/interactive/functions-string.html#FUNCTIONS-STRING-OTHER) function for this purpose:

```
SELECT entry
  FROM regexp_split_to_table('Mary=123=456=payment', '=') AS t(entry);
```

You can check output on [SQL Fiddle](http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!1/d41d8/204).

Answer (score 0):

On Oracle you have to use

```
select substr(description, 1, instr(description, '=') - 1) part1,
   substr(description, instr(description, '=') + 1,
                       instr(description, '=', 1, 2) - instr(description, '=') - 1) part2,
   substr(description, instr(description, '=', 1, 2) + 1,
                       instr(description, '=', 1, 3) - instr(description, '=', 1, 2) - 1) part3,
   substr(description, instr(description, '=', 1, 3) + 1) part4
from your_table;
```

MySQL has similar construct.

Comment: [instr in mysql](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/string-functions.html#function_instr)  function is different with instr(oracle) . it always returns the position of the first occurrence of substring substr in string str.